# Pandas dataframe concatenation and append issue

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation, append

## create an empty dataframe to store the sampled data

```
`sampled_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_concat.columns)

for Stratacluster, sample_size in res.items():
    Stratacluster_data = df_concat[df_concat['Strata Cluster'] == Stratacluster]
    sample = Stratacluster_data.sample(n=sample_size, random_state=42)
    sampled_df = sampled_df.append(sample)`
```

Error : FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.

Creating a dataframe by looping over a dictionary key and value and extracting sample from existing dataframe on the basic of key and value. and finally appending results into the created dataframe

Answer (score 0):

That is a warning, still you can use the append() if you want to. If you want to use concat() use the below code

```
df_list = []
for Stratacluster, sample_size in res.items():
    Stratacluster_data = df_concat[df_concat['Strata Cluster'] == Stratacluster]
    sample = Stratacluster_data.sample(n=sample_size, random_state=42)
    df_list.append(sample)
final_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```